# matlab fsolve changes in version 2012a

Tags: matlab

I have an fsolve in an m file and it works perfectly in version 2011b.  However, the fsolve fails each time in 2012a.  Has there been a major change to eithre the function or the options that would cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what R2012a Release Notice saying about `fsolve`:

> **Levenberg-Marquardt Algorithm Tweak**
>
> The fsolve, lsqcurvefit, and lsqnonlin solvers no longer use the
>   magnitude of the Levenberg-Marquardt regularization parameter as a
>   stopping criterion, so they no longer return an exit flag of -3 when
>   using the levenberg-marquardt algorithm. Instead, they use the TolX
>   tolerance in all internal calculations.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/rn/bs86_xz.html#btd80ns

Answer (score 1):

You might want to compare it from the documentation of the [current release](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fsolve.html) and the [older releases](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/doc-archives.html).